# Writing the input arguments in an anonymous function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, input, anonymous-function

I have the following code:

```
s(i+1)=NRK(Dt*f(tv(i+1),x)+s(i)-x,s(i));
```

Where `NRK=NRK(function , numeric scalar)` This was the symbolic implementation, with f=symbolic function, and x a symbolic array of unknowns.

The thing is that working with symbolic expressions can solve the issue, but this goes inside a loop, and symbolic tools slow down suprisingly the performance in a ratio of 100 times! However, anonymous functions do a perfect job.

My try was the following:

```
h=@([arguments (i.e. a, b, c, ...])Dt*f(t(i+1),[arguments (i.e. a, b, c,...])+s(i)-[a b c ...];
s(i+1)=NRK(@h,s(i));
```

How can I write these arguments? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify them in the parenthesis:

```
h = @( a, b, c ) Dt*f( t(ii+1), a, b, c ) + s(ii);
```

Then call

```
s(ii+1) = NRK( h, s(ii) );
```

Some remarks:
- You do not need to write an extra `@` when providing `h` to `NRK`, since `h` is already defined as a function handle.
- It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).